# How to switch back to VS 2022 closed outlining style

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2022

In the latest Visual Studio 2022 update 17.9.0, they changed the closed outlining style to be like in VSCode

Current:

[image: new style]

Previous one:

[image]

Is there an option to switch back to the old one?

Comment: i was looking for that too, hope you ll get an answer !

Comment: i didnt really found any answer to that, i think we could post about somewhere in the official Visual Studio channels, but i dont know where to so.

Comment: As info, you can add your comments to the Microsoft Feedback for this issue here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Outlining-in-179-uses-ugly-v-for-coll/10584634